# Three.js: using RawShaderMaterial with LineSegments

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on a three.js scene that renders points and line segments. [The scene](https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/visualizations/line-segments-network/) renders fine if I use a LineBasicMaterial material for the lines:

```js
/**
* constructor for the gl manager
**/

function World() {
  this.renderTarget = document.querySelector('#render-target');
  this.scene = this.getScene();
  this.camera = this.getCamera();
  this.renderer = this.getRenderer();
  this.controls = this.getControls();
  this.masterCounts = null; // {id: nMasters}
  this.edges = null; // 2d array where [[master, app, app]]
  this.positions = null; // {id: [x,y]}
  this.z = 0; // flat z dim
  this.loadData();
  this.render();
}

World.prototype.getScene = function() {
  return new THREE.Scene();
}

World.prototype.getContainerSize = function() {
  var elem = this.renderTarget;
  return {
    w: elem.clientWidth,
    h: elem.clientHeight,
  }
}

World.prototype.getCamera = function() {
  var size = this.getContainerSize();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, size.w/size.h, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.set(0.5, 0.5, -0.67);
  return camera;
}

World.prototype.getRenderer = function() {
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
  var size = this.getContainerSize();
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(size.w, size.h);
  document.querySelector('#render-target').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  return renderer;
}

World.prototype.getControls = function() {
  var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
  controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
  controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
  controls.target.set(0.5, 0.5, 1);
  return controls;
}

World.prototype.render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
  this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  this.controls.update();
}

World.prototype.getPointScale = function() {
  return window.devicePixelRatio * window.innerHeight * 0.00001;
}

World.prototype.loadData = function() {
  get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/visualizations/line-segments-network/node-positions-twopi.json', function(data) {
    this.positions = center(JSON.parse(data));
    get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/visualizations/line-segments-network/id-to-aggregate-masters.json', function(data) {
      this.masterCounts = JSON.parse(data);
      get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/visualizations/line-segments-network/edges.json', function(data) {
        this.edges = JSON.parse(data);
        this.addPoints();
        this.addEdges();
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
  }.bind(this));
}

World.prototype.addPoints = function() {

  var geometry  = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry(),
      translations = getPointTranslations(this.positions),
      colors = getColors(this.positions, this.masterCounts);

  geometry.addAttribute('position',
    new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array([0, 0, 0]), true, 3));
  geometry.addAttribute('translation',
    new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(translations, 3, true, 1) );
  geometry.addAttribute('target',
    new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(translations, 3, true, 1) );
  geometry.addAttribute('color',
    new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(colors, 3, true, 1) );

  this.points = new THREE.Points(geometry, this.getShaderMaterial());
  this.points.frustumCulled = false; // prevent mesh click on drag
  this.scene.add(this.points);
}

World.prototype.addEdges = function() {
  var indices = [],
      positions = [],
      idToIndex = {}, // {node id: index in edgePositions}
      ids = Object.keys(this.edges);
  // flatten edges into [[s,t],[s,t]]
  for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
    var idEdges = this.edges[ids[i]];
    for (var j=0; j<idEdges.length; j++) {
      // here ids[i] is a master node id, idEdges is list of
      // apprentice node ids
      var masterId = ids[i];
      var apprenticeId = idEdges[j];
      if (!(masterId in idToIndex)) {
        idToIndex[masterId] = positions.length;
        positions.push(this.positions[masterId]);
      }
      if (!(apprenticeId in idToIndex)) {
        idToIndex[apprenticeId] = positions.length;
        positions.push(this.positions[apprenticeId]);
      }
      indices = indices.concat([
        idToIndex[masterId],
        idToIndex[apprenticeId]
      ]);
    }
  }

  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry(),
      translations = new Float32Array(3*positions.length),
      iter = 0,
      indices = new Uint16Array(indices);
  for (var i=0; i<positions.length; i++) {
    var e = positions[i];
    translations[iter++] = e[0];
    translations[iter++] = e[1];
    translations[iter++] = this.z;
  }

  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xee6559,
    opacity: 0.3,
    transparent: true,
  })

  geometry.addAttribute('position',
    new THREE.BufferAttribute(translations, 3, true, 1));
  geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 1, true, 1));

  this.lines = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
  this.lines.frustumCulled = false; // prevent mesh click on drag
  this.scene.add(this.lines);
}

World.prototype.getShaderMaterial = function() {
  return new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: find('#vertex-shader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: find('#fragment-shader').textContent,
    uniforms: {
      transitionPercent: { type: 'f', value: 0.0 },
      pointScale: { type: 'f', value: this.getPointScale(), },
    }
  });
}

/**
* Helpers
**/

function get(url, handleSuccess, handleErr, handleProgress) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        if (handleSuccess) handleSuccess(xmlhttp.responseText)
      } else {
        if (handleErr) handleErr(xmlhttp)
      }
    };
  };
  xmlhttp.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (handleProgress) handleProgress(e);
  };
  xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
};

function find(querySelector) {
  return document.querySelector(querySelector);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  var size = world.getContainerSize();
  world.camera.aspect = size.w / size.h;
  world.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  world.renderer.setSize(size.w, size.h);
})

function center(data) {
  var ids = Object.keys(data);
  // find the domains of each axis in the data
  var p = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
      n = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
      domains = {x: {min: p, max: n}, y: {min: p, max: n}};
  for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
    vals = data[ids[i]];
    if (vals[0] < domains.x.min) domains.x.min = vals[0];
    if (vals[0] > domains.x.max) domains.x.max = vals[0];
    if (vals[1] < domains.y.min) domains.y.min = vals[1];
    if (vals[1] > domains.y.max) domains.y.max = vals[1];
  }
  // center each axis 0:1
  for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
    var d = data[ids[i]];
    d[0] = (d[0]-domains.x.min)/(domains.x.max-domains.x.min);
    d[1] = (d[1]-domains.y.min)/(domains.y.max-domains.y.min);
  }
  return data;
}

function getPointTranslations(data) {
  var ids = Object.keys(data);
  var arr = new Float32Array(ids.length*3),
      iter = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
    arr[iter++] = data[ids[i]][0];
    arr[iter++] = data[ids[i]][1];
    arr[iter++] = world.z;
  }
  return arr;
}

function getColors(data, masterCounts) {
  var ids = Object.keys(data);
  var maxMasters = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
    if (masterCounts[ids[i]] > maxMasters) maxMasters = masterCounts[ids[i]];
  }
  var colors = [
    '#1f77b4', '#86abd7', '#cbcdd3', '#f8dba8',
    '#eec570', '#eba055', '#ee6559',
  ];
  var arr = new Float32Array(ids.length * 3),
      iter = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
    var nMasters = Math.min(colors.length, masterCounts[ids[i]] || 0);
    var hex = colors[ Math.floor(colors.length * (nMasters / maxMasters)) ];
    var c = hexToRgb(hex);
    arr[iter++] = c.r / 255;
    arr[iter++] = c.g / 255;
    arr[iter++] = c.b / 255;
  }
  return arr;
}

function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? '0' + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return '#' + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

function hexToRgb(hex) {
  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16),
  } : {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0};
}

var world = new World();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#efefef, #efefef);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div#select-target {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  font-family: 'Mallory';
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: '';
  border: none;
  padding: 7px 40px 7px 10px;
  background-image: url(down-caret.png);
  background-position: 90% 50%;
  background-size: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
#render-container {
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#render-target {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div id='render-container'>
  <div id='select-target'></div>
  <div id='render-target'></div>
</div>

<script src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/visualizations/line-segments-network/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/visualizations/line-segments-network/trackball-controls.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/visualizations/line-segments-network/tweenlite.min.js'></script>

<script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
precision highp float;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform float transitionPercent;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
uniform float pointScale;

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 translation;
attribute vec3 target;
attribute vec3 color;

varying vec3 vColor;

float scalePointZ(in vec4 pos, in vec3 cameraPosition) {
  float zDelta = pow(pos[2] - cameraPosition[2], 2.0);
  float delta  = pow(zDelta, 0.5);
  float scaled = pointScale / delta;
  return scaled;
}

void main() {
  vec3 t1 = position + translation;
  vec3 t2 = position + target;
  vec3 pos = mix(t1, t2, clamp(transitionPercent, 0.0, 1.0));
  vec4 mvPos = modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPos;
  gl_PointSize = 6.0;
  vColor = color;
}
</script>

<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
precision highp float;

varying vec3 vColor;

void main() {
  // make points circular
  vec2 coord = gl_PointCoord - vec2(0.5);
  if (length(coord) > 0.5) discard;

  // set point color
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
</script>
```

I have been struggling to achieve the same scene using the rawshadermaterial for the lines, however. Here's one of the ways I've tried to set up the lines for the raw shader material:

```
World.prototype.addEdges = function() {

        var indices = [],
      positions = [],
      idToIndex = {}, // {node id: index in edgePositions}
      ids = Object.keys(this.edges);
  // flatten edges into [[s,t],[s,t]]
  for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
    var idEdges = this.edges[ids[i]];
    for (var j=0; j<idEdges.length; j++) {
      // here ids[i] is a master node id, idEdges is list of
      // apprentice node ids
      var masterId = ids[i];
      var apprenticeId = idEdges[j];
      if (!(masterId in idToIndex)) {
        idToIndex[masterId] = positions.length;
        positions.push(this.positions[masterId]);
      }
      if (!(apprenticeId in idToIndex)) {
        idToIndex[apprenticeId] = positions.length;
        positions.push(this.positions[apprenticeId]);
      }
      indices = indices.concat([
        idToIndex[masterId],
        idToIndex[apprenticeId]
      ]);
    }
  }

  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry(),
      translations = new Float32Array(3*positions.length),
      iter = 0,
      indices = new Uint16Array(indices);
  for (var i=0; i<positions.length; i++) {
    var e = positions[i];
    translations[iter++] = e[0];
    translations[iter++] = e[1];
    translations[iter++] = this.z;
  }

  var material = this.getShaderMaterial().clone();

  geometry.addAttribute('position',
    new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([0, 0, 0]), 3, true, 1));
  geometry.addAttribute('translation',
    new THREE.BufferAttribute(translations, 3, true, 1));
  geometry.addAttribute('target',
    new THREE.BufferAttribute(translations, 3, true, 1));
  geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 1, true, 1));

  this.lines = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
  this.lines.frustumCulled = false; // prevent mesh click on drag
  this.scene.add(this.lines);
}
```

However this renders nothing. Does anyone know how I can render the lines above with the raw shader material defined above? Any pointers or suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this happens because you are using `gl_PointCoord` in the fragment shader although you are not rendering points but lines. If I remove the following two lines of code, your lines are rendered:

```
vec2 coord = gl_PointCoord - vec2(0.5);
if (length(coord) > 0.5) discard;
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldynhxkq/

Maybe it's better to use different shader programs for both primitives.

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks @Mungen87. Seems like a funny quirk of the shader but I'll work around it...